How does a laptop output HDMI while a monitor takes in an HDMI?
I am relatively new to HDMI. We all know that if we want to display an image to a bigger screen, we use either HDMI or DP. But, a laptop's HDMI is an output while a monitor's (or TV's) HDMI is an input. How does that work? Looking at a pinout gives:

15 and 16 are called DDC (I2c) (15 for clock, 16 for data). I thought that DDC meant data direction control, but that does not make sense as there would only be one pin for it. Did more research and found that DDC means Display Data Conrol. So, how does a laptop output HDMI  while a monitor takes in an HDMI (i.e. what pin(s) are responsible for controlling the direction and/or what circuitry is involved in doing so, if the pin(s) aren't the only thing affecting the direction)?

I'm not clear on what the problem is. An Output produces data. An Input consumes data. Connecting an output to an input connects the producer to the consumer - so data 'flows' from the output/producer (laptop) to the input/consumer (display).

My question is how the laptop outputs the data while the monitor inputs the data (i.e. what pin(s) are responsible for doing so?)

Think about it this way: How does your wall outlet output power and your toaster take power as an input? What happens if you plug your toaster into your coffee maker?

Did you google HDMI Pinout? Does that answer your question?

@brhans that is what i did. and no it did not help


So, how does a laptop output HDMI while a monitor takes in an HDMI?

The port is more than just the physical shell and pins - it's also the circuitry, and that circuitry is different on the laptop and monitor side, even though the connector (and its documented pinout) look the same.
For the most part, the data pins in HDMI are designated as going from source to display (i.e. from the laptop to the monitor). In the HDMI output chip in the laptop, the physical circuitry attached to these pins will drive them (i.e. it's physically got output buffers containing transistors driving the pins subject to whatever signalling standard is applicable for that pin). In the monitor, those pins are attached to input buffers that react to voltage on the pins.
For the TMDS pins, these are quite literally twisted pairs of metal wires - the laptop applies current to them in a way that produces a clean signal without reflection/jank, and the monitor detects a current/voltage across the two wires at the other end.

what pin(s) are responsible for doing so

The same pin on both ends. For example, the HDMI protocol designates that a timing signal is sent on the two pins TMDS clock+ and TMDS clock-. One of the twisted pairs of wires in the cable is attached to these two pins at both ends.
At the end of the cable plugged into the laptop, the physical pins of metal in the connector that are numbered 10 and 12 carry the timing from the laptop into the cable, and at the other end of the cable, the physical pins at the same exact positions 10 and 12 carry the signal from the cable into the monitor.

DDC is different from the other pins in that it's an open-drain bus (I2C) - the two sides cooperatively share one signal line to communicate back and forth to each other, following a specific protocol that describes when and how each side should apply a low voltage to that signal line to communicate a particular message.

can you show me what an example circuitry looks like (e.g. if I were making my own hdmi video card)

@SnappyRiffs The example circuitry is rather complex, and wouldn't fit into a single answer (if you really designed wanted to see it at the transistor/circuit level) - it's a rather high-speed signal, with a lot of considerations for signal integrity and performance. In short, a TMDS transmitter/driver at one end, a TMDS receiver/decoder at another. I would highly discourage trying to DIY it unless you have enough background in high-speed circuit design already (and/or the right FPGA devboard). Look at the spec Justme mentions to see just how involved it all is

(e.g. the DVI 1.0 spec alone, before additional improvements + the jump to HDMI, is 76 pages)

@SnappyRiffs TB-FMCH-HDMI4K is a HDMI interface for Xilinx FPGA evaluation boards. See Video Processing Subsystem Reference Design for an example of where it is used.

The video is transferred on the high speed data and clock wires, differentially, using current mode logic levels and a form of 8b10b encoding that minimizes transitions and DC baseline wander by selecting the encoded symbols based on running bit balance disparity.
The laptop has a role of "source" and drives bits to cable and monitor has a role of "sink" that receives the bits through cable.
The electrical interface is identical to DVI, for further info about any aspect, feel free to read the publicly available DVI specification, or one of the early HDMI specifications that are (or at least were) publicly available.

I think you may have missed the point of the question which is (paraphrased) how the HDMI knows which way the data is flowing when the connectors and pinouts are the same on the transmitter and receiver. (The answer being that the laptop port only transmits and the monitor port only receives.)

@Transistor It flows the same way even if pinout is different like on DisplayPort. I updated the info on the device roles to be more specific.
